# moving an object without affecting other objects (using opengl)

Tags: c++, c, opengl

I've created a program with a few objects (houses, buildings). I want to move one object(square) without affecting other objects, but when I do other objects disappear.

How can I move an object without causing existing objects to disappear?

```
#include <glut.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

float wall1[4][2] = {{100,200},{100,100},{300,100},{300,200}};
float roof1 [3][2] = {{100,200},{200,250},{300,200}};
float door1 [4][2] = {{175,100},{175,150},{225,150},{225,100}};

float wall2 [4][2] = {{500,600},{500,500},{700,500},{700,600}};
float roof2 [3][2] = {{500,600},{600,650},{700,600}};
float door2 [4][2] = {{575,500},{575,550},{625,550},{625,500}};

float wall3[4][2] = {{100,1000},{100,900},{300,900},{300,1000}};
float roof3 [3][2] = {{100,1000},{200,1050},{300,1000}};
float door3 [4][2] = {{175,900},{175,950},{225,950},{225,900}};

float wall4[4][2] = {{900,200},{900,100},{1100,100},{1100,200}};
float roof4 [3][2] = {{900,200},{1000,250},{1100,200}};
float door4 [4][2] = {{975,100},{975,150},{1025,150},{1025,100}};


float wall5[4][2] = {{200,1300},{200,1200},{400,1200},{400,1300}};
float roof5 [3][2] = {{200,1300},{300,1350},{400,1300}};
float door5 [4][2] = {{275,1200},{275,1250},{325,1250},{325,1200}};

float wall6[4][2] = {{1100,700},{1100,600},{1300,600},{1300,700}};
float roof6 [3][2] = {{1100,700},{1200,750},{1300,700}};
float door6 [4][2] = {{1175,600},{1175,650},{1225,650},{1225,600}};


float build1[4][2]={{1000,1000},{1100,1000},{1100,1400},{1000,1400}};
float build2[4][2]={{1100,1000},{1200,1000},{1200,1300},{1100,1300}};



void myinit()

{
glClearColor(0.0,1.0,0.0,1.0);
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluOrtho2D(0,1500,0,1500);   
}

void drawhouse()

{

int i;
glColor3f(1,1,0);
glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
for(i=0;i<4;i++)
    glVertex2fv(wall1[i]);
glEnd();
glColor3f(10,0,0);
glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
for(i=0;i<3;i++)
    glVertex2fv(roof1[i]);
glEnd();
glColor3f(0,0,1);
glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
for(i=0;i<4;i++)
    glVertex2fv(door1[i]);
glEnd();
glColor3f(1,1,0);
glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
for(i=0;i<4;i++)
    glVertex2fv(wall2[i]);
glEnd();
glColor3f(10,0,0);
glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
for(i=0;i<3;i++)
    glVertex2fv(roof2[i]);
glEnd();
glColor3f(0,0,1);
glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
for(i=0;i<4;i++)
    glVertex2fv(door2[i]);
glEnd();
glColor3f(1,1,0);
glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
for(i=0;i<4;i++)
    glVertex2fv(wall3[i]);
glEnd();
glColor3f(10,0,0);
glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
for(i=0;i<3;i++)
    glVertex2fv(roof3[i]);
glEnd();
glColor3f(0,0,1);
glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
for(i=0;i<4;i++)
    glVertex2fv(door3[i]);
glEnd();

glColor3f(1,1,0);
glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
for(i=0;i<4;i++)
    glVertex2fv(wall4[i]);
glEnd();
glColor3f(10,0,0);
glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
for(i=0;i<3;i++)
    glVertex2fv(roof4[i]);
glEnd();
glColor3f(0,0,1);
glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
for(i=0;i<4;i++)
    glVertex2fv(door4[i]);
glEnd();
glColor3f(1,1,0);
glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
for(i=0;i<4;i++)
    glVertex2fv(wall5[i]);
glEnd();
glColor3f(10,0,0);
glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
for(i=0;i<3;i++)
    glVertex2fv(roof5[i]);
glEnd();
glColor3f(0,0,1);
glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
for(i=0;i<4;i++)
    glVertex2fv(door5[i]);
glEnd();
glColor3f(1,1,0);
glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
for(i=0;i<4;i++)
    glVertex2fv(wall6[i]);
glEnd();
glColor3f(10,0,0);
glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
for(i=0;i<3;i++)
    glVertex2fv(roof6[i]);
glEnd();
glColor3f(0,0,1);
glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
for(i=0;i<4;i++)
    glVertex2fv(door6[i]);
glEnd();
glutPostRedisplay();

}

void company()

{

int i;
glColor3f(0,0,1);
glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
for(i=0;i<4;i++)
    glVertex2fv(build1[i]);
glEnd();
glColor3f(0.5,0,0.5);
glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
for(i=0;i<4;i++)
    glVertex2fv(build2[i]);
glEnd();
glutPostRedisplay();

}

void path1(int value)

{

float i;

for(i=0;i<270;i=i+0.1)
{
glColor3f(1.0,0.0,0.0);
glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
glVertex2f(1000.0+i,1000.0-i);
glVertex2f(1050.0+i,1000.0-i);
glVertex2f(1050.0+i,1050.0-i);
glVertex2f(1000.0+i,1050.0-i);
glEnd();
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
glutTimerFunc(200000,drawhouse, 0);
glFlush();

}

}



void display()

{

glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);   
drawhouse();
company();
glPushMatrix(); 
path1(0);
glPopMatrix();

glFlush();
glutSwapBuffers();

}

void main(int argc,char** argv)

{

glutInit(&argc,argv);
glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB);
glutInitWindowSize(800,800);
glutInitWindowPosition(0,0);
glutCreateWindow("House ");
myinit();
glutDisplayFunc(display);
glutMainLoop();

}
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I have a feeling it's probably for the code dump. Posting only relevant code is a good exercise for two reasons 1) it demonstrates that you've tried different techniques to solve the problem and have identified the problematic areas to some extent and 2) it makes it easier to read.

Comment: And with regards to making it easier to read, proper indentation also helps.

Comment: What do you mean move an object? Do you want to make something like a Camera?

Answer (score 2):

Go to your local library and get one of the usual opengl books (for example "Beginning OpenGL Programming") and carefully read the first couple of chapters. This will help you far more than any answer you might get to your question. You seem to have not yet grasped the basic concepts. This is by no means meant as an insult nobody was born with any of this knowledge.

To archive what you want to do you might want to pay special attention to: manipulating the matrix stack, scene graphs, objectspace vs. worldspace vs. camera space and transformations in general.

Cheers
Kai